# async/await with Limiter for sending requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, rate-limiting

I'm trying to limit the number of requests I send to an API.
I'm using Limiter and it's working just like I need, the only issue is that I can't find a way to use it with await (I need all the responses before rendering my page)
Can someone give me a hand with it?

Btw the Log returns a boolean.

```
const RateLimiter = require('limiter').RateLimiter;

const limiter = new RateLimiter(50, 5000)

for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfOrders.length; i++) {
    const response = limiter.removeTokens(1, async (err, remainingRequests) => {
        console.log('request')
        return await CoreServices.load('updateOrder', {
            "OrderNumber": arrayOfOrders[i],
            "WorkFlowID": status
        })
    })
    console.log('response', response)
}

console.log('needs to log after all the request');
```

this is loggin:

```
response true
response true
response false
needs to log after all the request
request
request
request
...
```

Comment: In your case `.map()` is going to return an array of promises.  If you want to wait for all those to be done, then you will need to do `await Promise.all(arrayOfOrders.map(...))`.  Or, if you're OK with sequencing them, change the `.map()` to a regular `for` loop and then the `await` inside the loop will actually do something useful.  Keep in mind that `.map()` is not promise or `await` aware so `return await Coreservices.load(...)` isn't waiting for anything.  It's just returning a promise to `.map()`.

Comment: that's not the issue, using for it's not working either. It's still not waiting for all the request to be finished to continue. I believe it's something with limiter.

Comment: updated the code with the idea from @jfriend00

Comment: I don't know what `limiter.removeTokens()` is supposed to be doing, but you're doomed to control the flow if you're mixing promises and regular callbacks.  You can't control it.  I guess you can promisify `limiter.removeTokens()` and then `await` that result.

Comment: the for loop doesn't wait for "inner" asynchronous code ... you need to understand that the code in the for loop is probably running correctly (limited) - the console log doesn't mean it's not working, so there's nothing wrong with the limiter

Comment: the limiter is working perfectly, but as I need to render the responses on a page, I must wait for all them before continuing.

Comment: @jfriend00 limiter.removeTokens returns a boolean right away, so promisy it is not an option I guess.

Comment: How can it return a boolean right away when you're feeding it a promise?  I don't get it.  If it just returns a boolean, then you have no way of waiting for all the promises.  I guess I don't know what problem you're trying to solve any more.

Comment: the value returned by `limiter.removeTokens` is described as follows: `@returns {Boolean} True if the callback was fired immediately, otherwise false` but your code (and **all** example code in the library itself) doesn't use the return value so it's irrelevant to your issue

Comment: got you @JaromandaX! added only for making it clear it does not returns a promise

Comment: Check the answer - I think it'll do what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promisifying `.removeTokens` will help, see if this code works

```
const RateLimiter = require('limiter').RateLimiter;

const limiter = new RateLimiter(50, 5000);

const tokenPromise = n => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    limiter.removeTokens(n, (err, remainingRequests) => {
        if (err) {
            reject(err);
        } else {
            resolve(remainingRequests);
        }
    });
});
(async() => { // this line required only if this code is top level, otherwise use in an `async function`
    const results = await Promise.all(arrayOfOrders.map(async (order) => {
        await tokenPromise(1);
        console.log('request');
        return CoreServices.load('updateOrder', {
            "OrderNumber": order,
            "WorkFlowID": status
        });
    }));
    console.log('needs to log after all the request');
})(); // this line required only if this code is top level, otherwise use in an `async function`
```

explanation

Firstly:

```
const tokenPromise = n => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    limiter.removeTokens(n, (err, remainingRequests) => {
        if (err) {
            reject(err);
        } else {
            resolve(remainingRequests);
        }
    });
});
```

promisifies the `limiter.removeTokens` to use in async/await - in nodejs you could use the built in promisifier, however lately I've had too many instances where that fails - so a manual promisification (I'm making up a lot of words here!) works just as well

Now the code is easy - you can use `arrayOfOrders.map` rather than a for loop to create an array of promises that all run parallel as much as the rate limiting allows, (the rate limiting is done inside the callback)

`await Promise.all(...` will wait until all the `CoreServices.load` have completed (or one has failed - you could use `await Promise.allSettled(...` instead if you want)

The code in the map callback is tagged `async` so:

```
await tokenPromise(1);
```

will wait until the `removeTokens` callback is called - and then the request

```
return CoreServices.load
```

is made

Note, this was originally `return await CoreServices.load` but the await is redundant, as `return await somepromise` in an async function is just the same as `return somepromise` - so, adjust your code too

Comment: Wow! thanks a lot man. worked perfectly, exactly what I needed. If don't mind, try explaining what you did so I don't bother you again next time hehe.

Comment: @PedroZancopé - added some explanation - note ... I did change the code, removed the await in `return await CoreServices.load` as the await there is redundant

Comment: @PedroZancopé also, changed the code at `"OrderNumber": arrayOfOrders[i],` as that was wrong - it should be `"OrderNumber": order,` - which I see you already picked up on!! Thanks